# SQL server Convert the row into column and print the table data

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2012

[image: Conver the Row into column]

I am trying to convert the below data into column value and print the data.

Database : SQL server

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select id,
       max(case when attb_name = 'Job name' then value end) as job_name,
       max(case when attb_name = 'Created date' then value end) as created_date,
       max(case when attb_name = 'Created by' then value end) as created_by,
       max(case when attb_name = 'Job type' then value end) as job_type
from t
group by id;
```

Comment: Thanks for you help, Actually my column not fixed, there are number of column, can you pls share me dynamic query

Comment: Above table value getting after using below query 

SELECT _ID, ATTRB_NM, value
FROM abc v
WHERE v.type = 'BIGDATA'
ORDER BY 1;

-------------------------
MY ACTUAL QUERY IS Where condition so that, Aggregate function with group by clause getting Error